# HTML Scrolling Tables- Lock a Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to essentially 'freeze' a column in an HTML table, similar to what can be done in Excel.  However, I need to be able to scroll in both directions.  I am currently trying to do this by using a vertically-scrollable div to hold a table, which on the left holds a list of names and on the right holds a horizontally-scrollable div with the data pertaining to those names.  Each of these will have a fixed-div to hold the column title data.  The problem is that with this method, the horizontal-scroll bar is at the bottom of the div, which is only viewable if you scroll to the very bottom.  Is there any way to fix the location of this scrollbar to the bottom of the outer div?  I'm sure there must be some sort of solution here, but I havent' found it yet.  Any help would be much appreciated.

**NOTE:**  I also have JavaScript / JQuery available to me for this site.

**EDIT:** As requested, here is the markup I am currently working with:

```
<div id='am_verticalScrollerDiv' style='height: 440px; overflow-y: auto;'>" +
    <table id='am_verticalScrollerLayoutTable' height='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
        <tr>
            <td id='am_resourceListCell'>
                <div id='am_resourceListDiv'>
                    <table id='am_resourceTitleTable' width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                        <tr id='am_resource_tableTitleBar'></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <table id='am_resourceList' width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td id='am_horizScrollCell'>
                <div id='am_horizScrollDiv' style='width:900px; overflow-x: auto;'>
                    <div id='am_schedDataTitleBarDiv'>
                        <table id='am_schedDataTitleBarTable>
                            <tr class='am_schedule_formatBar'></tr>
                            <tr id='am_schedule_tableTitleBar' style='font-family: \"Courier New\", Courier, monospace; font-size: 12px;'></tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <table id='am_scheduleDisplay' width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='table-layout: fixed; empty-cells: show;'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr class='am_schedule_formatBar'></tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried.

Comment: All data is added via JavaScript

Comment: BTW, sorry for using all inline style- there are so many restrictions on the server that I can't actually add a stylesheet (or place my JavaScript into separate files).

Comment: I suspect overlaying an iframe with the same table in it in the column position may be easiest way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion- I don't know much about iframes yet, so I'll read up on them.

Comment: I just realized, I'm not sure that an iframe would work here.  I still need the left column to scroll with the right one vertically, just not horizontally.  I may be missing something, but I don't see how the iframe will fix this problem.